# Do they have credit cards in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

While recently thinking about a scene from the Clone Wars series where Anakin (and possibly Asoka) were paying for something with a number of physical credits, it dawned on me that I have never seen anyone pay with a credit or debit card in Star Wars. So, **do credit or debit cards exist in Star Wars?**

Comment: credit as a concept certainly exists....at least debt does

Comment: Do they even have a galactic banking system?  A financial clearing system would seem to be a prerequisite...

Comment: That’s a good point....you’d think a galaxy advanced enough to have interstellar travel would at least have a credit system in their banking infrastructure. Either in the form of cards or some other ID to charge purchases cross-currency.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/InterGalactic_Banking_Clan at least during the prequel era

Comment: Credit cards are explicitly mentioned in the RPG game "Death in the Undercity" as one of the items carried by Quarren gangsters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, there was something of this sort**

> Watto:
> How are you going to pay for all this?
>
> Qui-Gon Jinn:
> I have twenty thousand Republic dataries.
>
> Watto:
> Republic credits? Republic credits are no good out here. I need something more real.
>
> Qui-Gon Jinn:
> I don't have anything else
>
> Qui-Gon Jinn:
> but credits will do fine.
>
> Watto:
> No, they won't-a.
>
> Qui-Gon Jinn:
> Credits will do fine.
>
> Watto:
> No, they won't-a. What? You think you're some kind of Jedi, waving your hand around like that? I'm a Toydarian, mind tricks don't work on me. Only money. No money, no parts, no deal!

So, we see from the very first hand canon that they have a different payment method than cash.

**Credit Stick**

According to Wookieepedia, [credit stick](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Credit_chip) is mentioned in several fan fictions along with some Clone Wars episodes and in some relatively canon games like *Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic*.

I assume it works as follows:

- An unbreakable and untamperable device, equivalent of POS machines is rented/purchased from a bank by the shop owner.
- This device reads the credit on paying stick and updates it. After this, it updates the receiving stick as well.
- The shop owner can withdraw the money using his credit stick from a bank branch or ATM.

However, this operation describes both the debit card and credit card. I guess if the balance on the credit stick is allowed to go down to a negative number, it acts more like a credit card.

**There is no need for real-time communication for credit cards**

[Touch memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_memory) technology allows transfer for money without the need of any communication. It is basically a reprogrammable RFID.

Comment: I think Republic Credits weren't acceptable to Watto because of Tatooine's distance from the Republic center, not because they weren't physical